# Wobbly Image while upscaling

Tags: html, css

I am applying 2 CSS3 transitions to a image. Everything works fine. Only issue. The image wobbles while upscaling. Is there any way to smoothen this out?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WxFpp/2/)

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:199px;
    height:253;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
div:hover
{   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition:all 2s linear;
}
```

***EDIT***: Somehow I notice that the issue is not with the upscale property. If you remove the hue-roate property the images upscales without any jitter. However I need both the effects in my animation.

Comment: Decrease the transition duration and you won't notice it?

Comment: @onetrickpony, That is the last resort. But i need a different way. The transition has to show hue change properly

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/WxFpp/25/ i added little bit rotation to transform scale.. may be this can help you

Comment: @VikasGhodke, the image upscale has to be only 1.2. Anyways. Dont see much change. Maybe i have been looking at that image for too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed the transition on the img and transitioned the width instead of scale and it seemed to fix the wobble

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/WxFpp/48/)**

```
div{

    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
img
{
    width:199px;
}
img:hover
{     width: 238px;
      -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
      -webkit-transition:all 2s linear;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah. This worked for me. Infact the tiger's whiskers appear to bristle a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the image is being scaled up along different axes at different times because it is not a square image and the floating-point dimensions are being truncated to integers.

The only fix that exists is to artificially make the image element square so that the two dimensions of the image are scaled up in sync, which will eliminate the perceived jitter.

Though, if I could get away with it, I probably just reduce the transition time so that the jitter is not as noticeable.

Comment: It is the scaling factor. I used : -webkit-transform: scale(1.20009); the 'wobble' was still there but not as noticable (Chrome browser)